# Como fazer efeito de corrida?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Preciso colocar um efeito nos carros para eles se moverem até esse ponto quando carregar a pagina.

Tem algum Jquery pra isso? 
Não sei nem se tem um nome para esse efeito rs

Também tenho que colocar essa borda no carrinho, como está o exemplo do primeiro(á direita).

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

[image: carros de corrida]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em que formato tens essa(s) imagens?

Comment: @Sergio estão num PSD! posso salvar como PNG

Comment: @HendyAlmeida Então, primeiro você tem que separar a imagem dos carros da imagem de fundo, se você tem o PSD provavelmente conseguirá fazer isto, se vc tiver un link com as imagens eu posso fazer e responder aqui

Comment: Adicionei a imagem do carrinho! (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar os estilos `transform` e `transition`. O primeiro pode ser utilizado para movimentar (de forma fácil e mais amigável para o browser) elementos na tela. O segundo serve para declarar que você quer animar a mudanças de certos estilos (no caso, o `transform`).

```
/* Os carros começam fora da tela */
.carro {
    /* movimenta o elemento no eixo X */
    transform: translateX(-2000px);
    transition: transform 1s;
}

/* Utilizando js, você adiciona uma classe para utilizar como seletor para deixar os carros na posição correta */
.largada .carro {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Para iniciar a animação, utilizando o código acima, basta adicionar a classe `largada` em um container acima dos carros.

Uma dica também é utilizar o estilo `transition-delay` que adiciona um delay antes da animação iniciar. Assim, você pode incrementar o delay para cada carro dando um pouco mais de vida para a sua animação.

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrsoLr8o/1/)

Comment: Funcionou! Obrgada (:

Answer (score 2):

Podes fazer isso com CSS e JavaScript.

No CSS defines as transicão que queres fazer e uma classe que define o novo valor de por exemplo `margin-left`:

```
#carros img {
    margin-left: -600px;
    transition: margin-left 1s;
}
.chegada {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

e no JavaScript precisar somente de adicionar essa classe de CSS passado algum tempo (3s no exemplo em baixo):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector('#carros img').classList.add('chegada');
}, 3000);
```

**Exemplo: [http://jsfiddle.net/uy0ajo3k/1](http://jsfiddle.net/uy0ajo3k/1__)** <sub>(agora com sufixos para browsers mais antigos)</sub>

Para fazer o efeito do carro com a borda amarela sugiro teres duas imagens diferentes e sobrepores a segunda que tem essa cor amarela depois.

Comment: O efeito só acontece quando tiro o margin-left: -600px pelo browser :/

Comment: Como funciona o Transition?

Comment: @HendyAlmeida qual é o browser que estás a usar? vês a imagem a mover-se passados 3 segundos da página carregar?

Comment: Chrome! 
No exemplo o efeito funciona, mas no meu projeto não !

Comment: Podes colocar o código do teu projeto? ou ainda melhor: adapta o jsFiddle com o teu código para reproduzir o problema e coloca aqui...

Comment: Consegui resolver! Obrigada pela ajuda, preciso estudar mais :D